# Bind list of object to Multi selection of DropdownlistFor and Submitform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two  class

```
class UserRequestModel
{
    public UserRequestModel()
    {
        ProfileRequest = new List<ProfileRequestModel>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<ProfileRequestModel> ProfileRequest { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileRequestModel
{
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
}
```

1. I want to use UserRequestModel as Model.
2. How to bind the multiple selection for Dropdownlistfor?
3. On submit form, In Controller
   public ActionResult SubmitForm(UserRequestModel obj)
   obj should contain the multiple selected values.

Comment: Is it `Class` or `class`?

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu, it is class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options as below:

1. Use `@Html.ListBox` to render and give option as multiple values in
   dropdown.

   So code in your views would look like below:

   ```
   @Html.ListBox(ViewBag.ProfileRequest as SelectList, new { @id = "ProfileRequest" })
   ```
2. Other option is to use `jquery.multiSelect.js` which can be found
   [here](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/multiselect/).

   So your listbox would be rendered by this plugin like below:

   ```
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.multiSelect.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $("#SelectedValues").multiSelect();
   });
   </script>


   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedValues, Model.ProfileRequest)
       <button type="submit">OK</button>
   }
   ```

   Next you can post your viewmodel

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(UserRequestModel model)
   {
     return View(model);
   }
   ```

**Reference Article** http://www.aspnetmvcninja.com/views/asp-net-mvc-select-list-example

Comment: thanks. using UserRequestModel i will get ID and List of profiles then how can i bind multiple profiles as selected into Dropdownlist

Comment: Your dropdown would bind to ProfileRequestModel `@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedValues, new SelectList(Model.ProfileRequest, "Value", "Text"))` then get the selected values `var sports = string.Join(",", model.SelectedValues)`